# Get value of a randomly generated jsf Table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, javabeans, managed-bean

I am new to this , i am using primefaces and generating a dynamic table, this datatable gets its vaules from a list created by a managed bean.

I need to set the property of another managed bean with the value of the column generated by the datatable.

Eg: Col1, has a particular value, i want to click on that value and a dialog box should appear displaying that col1 value

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="c" value="#{databaseSearch.customerList}"  
                                     paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                     paginatorTemplate="Page {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  Rows per page {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,30">     
<p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">  
      <h:outputText value="Machine" />  
    </f:facet>  
    <p:commandButton id="xxx" value="#{c.machine}" action="#{updateEntry.setMachine(c.machine)}" ajax="true" onclick="dlg1.show();" styleClass="ui-Machinebutton"/>
                                    <!-- styleClass="ui-Machinebutton" -->
                            </p:column>
```

The managed bean 'updateEntry' has getter and setter methods. 
**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UpdateEntry implements Serializable {

   public Long Machine;

    public Long getMachine() {
        return Machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Long Machine) {
        this.Machine = Machine;
    }


}
```

**Dialog Box**

```
<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="100" dynamic="True">  
<h:outputText value="#{updateEntry.machine}" />  
</p:dialog>
```

I do understand that in order to pass a parameter to the dialog box i would need the help of a managed bean. However, the datatable is generated randomly and i am not able to pass that particular random value. So how do i pass the random value of a command button and set the managed bean when it is clicked ?

**Objective**

When the command button is clicked, i want its value to be passed to a managed bean, since this is randomly generated dataTable, i am not sure how i can achieve that.

**Update**

It Works ! The same code updates updateEntry.machine but the problem is since clicking on the button opens the dialog box first before the updateEntry.machine is updated to a new value, the dialog box displays the previously clicked option. Does the 'Action' happen before the 'Onclick' ? or is it the other way around ? I need to update the bean first and then open the dialog box for it to show the newer value. I have tried both True & False  of the dynamic property of the dialog box, not sure what is that for.

Also i need to refresh the page to get the new value loaded in dialog box, else no matter which command button i click it shows me the value of the command button i first clicked, post the page refresh, it shows the value of the command button last clicked.

Answer (score 0):

u can declare a new object for `updateEntry` inside your current class, `c`
then in your action button, call a method in c to change updateEntry machine value such as:

```
<p:commandButton id="xxx" value="#{c.machine}" action="#{c.change()}" ajax="true" onclick="dlg1.show();" styleClass="ui-Machinebutton"/>
```

while in c class

```
private void change(){
        //set updateEntry.machine value here
    }
```

so your dialog box should look like

```
<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="100" dynamic="False">  
<h:outputText value="#{c.updateEntry.machine}" />  
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but C is a variable created to populate the datatable, i have updated the code for your reference. The point here is the 'CommandButton' has a randomly generated value, when i click on it, how can i get that randomly generated value ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ...

I changed the code to below and it worked !

```
<p:commandButton id="basic" value="#{c.machine}" action="#{updateEntry.setMachine(c.machine)}" ajax="true" oncomplete="dlg1.show();" styleClass="ui-Machinebutton"/>
```

The trick here was to first set the 'Machine' variable and upon completion load the dialog box which reads back the same 'Machine' variable